# WP Query post by year in accordion

Tags: php, wordpress, accordion, custom-post-type

I'm trying to get the testimonials (custom post type) in following order.

[image]

I can easily retrieve posts using WP_Query class but struggling to create an accordion as shown in the screenshot above.

Comment: can you post your code?

Answer (score 1):

[Try using a custom select query and looping through each post with a post_type of testimonial.](https://codex.wordpress.org/Displaying_Posts_Using_a_Custom_Select_Query)

Then loop through result and set `WP_Query() class` `date_query` param to an array of the years obtained by the custom select query result.

```
global $wpdb;

$posts = $wpdb->posts;

//Get all unique years as "years" from posts where post type is equal to testimonials

$sql = "SELECT DISTINCT(YEAR(`post_date`)) as years FROM $posts WHERE post_type = 'testimonials' ORDER BY years DESC"; //Get all post year list by DESC


//Loop through all results and use date_query param https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Date_Parameters


$result = $wpdb->get_results($sql);

foreach($result as $rs) {
    echo '<h2>'.$rs->years.'</h2>';
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'testimonials',
        'post_per_page'=> -1,
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'orderby'   => 'date',
        'order' => 'DESC',
        'date_query' => array(array(
            'year'=> $rs->years,
        ),),

    );

     $loop = new WP_Query($args);

     if($loop->have_posts()) {

        while($loop->have_posts()) : $loop->the_post();

            echo '<a href="'.get_permalink().'">'.get_the_date().'</a>';
        endwhile;

     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@user3325126 Great code, thanks :) 
Just replace 'post_per_page'=> -1, into 'posts_per_page'=> -1, (missing one s)
It should be

```html
'posts_per_page'=> -1,
```