# WordPress query: Group posts by year DESC, then posts by month ASC within each group

Tags: php, mysql, sql, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I'm trying to set up a WordPress query and loop such that events are grouped by year in **descending** order, with a heading for each year, and then ordered by month in **ascending** order for each year group, like so:

2020

- Jan 1, 2020
- Feb 1, 2020
- Mar 1, 2020

2019

- Jan 1, 2019
- Feb 1, 2019
- Mar 1, 2019

I have found some helpful threads here that point in the right direction, such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52492728/wp-query-post-by-year-in-accordion), which uses a direct SQL query to get the posts by year, and then runs the usual loop on `WP_Query` to group and sort the posts within each group. In my case, however, instead of using `post_date`, I have a custom field (using Advanced Custom Fields) for `event_end_date` that should define the order of the posts and group definitions.

The SQL query in the linked example is

```
$sql = "SELECT DISTINCT(YEAR(`post_date`)) as years FROM $posts WHERE post_type = 'testimonials' ORDER BY years DESC"; //Get all post year list by DESC

$result = $wpdb->get_results($sql);

foreach($result as $rs) {
    echo '<h2>'.$rs->years.'</h2>';
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'event',
        'post_per_page'=> -1,
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'orderby'   => 'date',
        'order' => 'DESC',
        'date_query' => array(array(
            'year'=> $rs->years,
        ),),

    );

     $loop = new WP_Query($args);

     if($loop->have_posts()) {

        while($loop->have_posts()) : $loop->the_post();

            echo '<a href="'.get_permalink().'">'.get_the_date().'</a>';
        endwhile;

     }
}
```

And I'm not quite sure how to modify it such that I can query the `event_end_date` custom field, and form the year groups, within which I can then list posts sorted by month ASC.

I'm assuming that I *need* to use a manual SQL query here in that a typical `WP_Query` would not allow for sorting in two different ways, as I've described? I can easily output the events into groups with headings for each year, but only in one set order, i.e. ASC or DESC. Thanks for any assistance here, and please let me know if this is unclear in any way.

Comment: `SELECT * FROM $posts WHERE post_type = 'testimonials' ORDER BY year(post_date) DESC, month(post_date) asc, day(post_date) asc`

Comment: thanks for the reply @lufc but I'm trying to use the custom field `event_end_date` to form the groups and order the posts, as described in my original post.

Comment: In which case it sounds like your question is "how can I apply multiple ORDER BY statements to a custom field in Wordpress". Which you can see here: https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/orde-posts-by-custom-fields/ and here: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/65769/multiple-orderby-values-in-wp-query

Comment: @lufc I understand how to use multiple orderby values and how to set order using a custom field- I'm trying to get groups of entries as described in my post

Comment: Create the query to list all of the events, ordered by year and then month. When you are looping over the events just check whether the year of the current row equals the year of the previous row, if it doesn't then insert some HTML to create the new group.

Comment: @lufc Ok, I see, I'll give that a try and report back- thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the Advanced Custom Fields' "Date Picker", here is how you sort by the posts' custom field a WP_Query:

```
<?php 
$year = '';
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page'    => -1,
    'meta_key'          => 'event_end_date',
    'orderby'           => 'meta_value_num',
    'order'             => 'DESC',
);
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
?>      
<?php if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : ?>
    <?php while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>

        <?php

        // create the date variables
        $event_date_string = get_field('event_end_date');
        $event_date = DateTime::createFromFormat('Ymd', $event_date_string);
        $event_year = $event_date->format('Y');

        // add header for each year
        if ($year != $event_year) :
           echo '<div><b>' . $event_year . '</b></div>';
           $year = $event_year;
        endif;

        // echo out current post
        echo '<div>' . $event_date . ': ' . get_the_title() . '</div>';

        ?>

    <?php endwhile; ?>
    <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Explanation:

1. Create a $year variable to keep track of the current year
2. Get all posts with a WP_Query and sort by 'event_end_date' in DESC order
3. Loop through posts and get the event year for each post which we use to update the $year variable

More information here:
https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/date-picker/

Comment: Hi @tokant, I appreciate the response, but that's essentially what I'm already doing. My question is how to shift the order- that is, have the year groups in DESC order, and the events within each group in ASC order, as described in my question.